# Два раза объявление переменной в java

Tags: java

Скачал исходный код, открыл в idea и увидел это:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как такое возможно? Причем компилятор ругается.

Так же в проекте видел запись вида:

```
int a = false;
```

UPD: нашел:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это?

Comment: "как это?" --- что "это" ? так можно, но смысла нет. потому что одно объявление перетирает другое

Comment: Как как... КАком. Видите же что подчёркнуто, значит ошибка, и работать не будет

Comment: Вы скачали проект с нерабочим кодом.  Обращайте внимание на подсказки IDE / сообщения компилятора об ошибках.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

убери одну переменную, и всё должно работать!
а точнее: int i;

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).